# Is there any way to get rid of the second while loop here?

Tags: algorithm, merge

For [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/), I have a working solution:

```
class Solution {
    public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
        int count = m+n-1;
        m--;
        n--;
        while(m>=0 && n>=0) {
            if(nums1[m]>nums2[n])
                nums1[count--] = nums1[m--];
            else
                nums1[count--] = nums2[n--];
        }
        while (n>=0) {
            nums1[count--] = nums2[n--];
        }
    }
}
```

But what I wanted to do is get rid of the second while loop.

I tried something like this:

```
class Solution {
    public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
        int count = m+n-1;
        m--;
        n--;
        while(m>=0 || n>=0) {
            if(m>=0 && n>=0 && nums1[m]>nums2[n])
                nums1[count--] = nums1[m--];
            else if(n>=0)
                nums1[count--] = nums2[n--];
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an array boundary exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is an IndexOutOfBoundsException? To me the problem seems to be that you will get an endless loop if n < 0 and m >= 0.

Here is a working solution, I basically just simplified yours and corrected the error:

```
class Solution {
    public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
        int count = m+n-1;
        m--;
        n--;
        while(n>=0) {
            if(m>=0 && nums1[m]>nums2[n])
                nums1[count--] = nums1[m--];
            else
                nums1[count--] = nums2[n--];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (To arrive at this loop termination condition, you have to realise that elements of `nums1` not handled when `nums2` is exhausted are in the correct positions already and thus don't have to be handled at all.)